# Jquery target parent up two levels checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, parent

I am having a problem trying to access a checkbox a few levels above my span.

```
<div class="control-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="employed_now" id="employed_now" class="checkbox-msg"/>
<label><span class="label label-success checkbox-msg">Yes</span>employed_now</label>
```

When `span.checkbox-msg` is clicked, I want to traverse up the dom to `input:checkbox` and check/uncheck the checkbox.

The following code does NOT work:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'span.checkbox-msg', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().find('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
    });
```

I can NOT use/target just the class name of "checkbox-msg" as there are other classes on the page.

How can I target the parent > parent to checkbox?

Comment: And where is this check-box to change, you've only shown the one in your html.

Comment: @DavidThomas - There is ONE checkbox. The span tag will check/uncheck that item. The checkbox is id=employed_now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.siblings()` and `.closest()` whichever suits you and you can use `.prop()` to check and uncheck:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

or

```
$(this).closest('.control-group').find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

[**Findout both here**](http://jsfiddle.net/axfMy/)

Answer (score 2):

You may do it this way:

```
    $(document).on('click', 'span.checkbox-msg', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input:checkbox', $(this).closest('div')).attr('checked','checked');
    });
```

But you may just add `for='employed_now'` attribute to your `<label>` and have the same function without jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'span.checkbox-msg', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).before('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
});
```